# Loop over averaging period within dplyr statement

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate variations of rolling average periods within an R dplyr statement.

```
    library(dplyr)

    data <- tibble(a=seq(1:1000), b=runif(1000), c=rep(c('x','y','Z','q'), 250))

    # Rolling mean calculation
    augment <- data %>% group_by(c) %>% mutate(mean = rollmean(a, 10, na.pad=TRUE, align='left')) %>%  
           ungroup() %>% drop_na() %>% group_by(c)  %>% dplyr::summarize(cor = cor(mean,b)) %>% 
           mutate(ndays = 10)
```

What I would like to do is loop over/iterate through the rolling period of 10 and replace 10 with seq(10,35).

This output of the above statement is:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  c         cor ndays
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 q      0.0107    10
2 x      0.0118    10
3 y     -0.0908    10
4 Z     -0.0508    10
```

The desired output is a tibble with an entry for ndays for each of the 10 through 35 averaging periods and the associated correlation.

I tried inserting a mutate statement to add an ndays variable but the dimensions are not correct.  Varies iterations on that attempt did not work.

How can this be achieved within dplyr and related packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick thing you can do is use `purrr` to apply the function to each value from 10 to 35:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

data <- tibble(a=seq(1:1000), b=runif(1000), c=rep(c('x','y','Z','q'), 250))

10:35 %>% 
  map_df(~{
    data %>% 
      group_by(c) %>%
      mutate(mean = rollmean(a, .x, na.pad=TRUE, align='left')) %>%  
      ungroup() %>% 
      drop_na() %>% 
      group_by(c)  %>% 
      dplyr::summarize(cor = cor(mean,b)) %>% 
      mutate(ndays = .x)
  })
#> # A tibble: 104 x 3
#>    c         cor ndays
#>    <chr>   <dbl> <int>
#>  1 q      0.0519    10
#>  2 x     -0.123     10
#>  3 y      0.0347    10
#>  4 Z     -0.116     10
#>  5 q      0.0571    11
#>  6 x     -0.111     11
#>  7 y      0.0379    11
#>  8 Z     -0.124     11
#>  9 q      0.0498    12
#> 10 x     -0.103     12
#> # … with 94 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's fantastic.  It works beautifully and I don't have to use a for loop.  Thank you for your input.